# ¿Obtener id de un enlace con etiqueta <a>?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema que no he podido resolver buscando en mil sitios de internet.
Tengo una página con código html y php en la que tengo varios input de tipo submit, generados con los valores de una base de datos.

```
<?php
        $BBDD = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'datosSrDinner');
        $consultaProductos = $BBDD->query("SELECT nombre, descripcion FROM productos");
        while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaProductos)){
            echo "<tr><td><a href='datosProducto.php'> - $mostrar[0] || $mostrar[1]</a></td></tr>";;
        }
        ?>
```

Y lo que quiero es que cuando se de en ese enlace, se redireccione a un código php que me va a generar la página con los datos de ese producto en concreto, para ello el id lleva el nombre del producto, que quiero usar después para hacer la consulta a la base de datos, en el otro documento de php y, así obtener solo los datos del producto con nombre X. Pero no se como pasarle esa información mediante el id para poder hacer la consulta.

Había pensado también en poner algo como:

```
<a href='datosProducto.php' onclick=$_SESSION['producto'] = $mostrar[0]> - $mostrar[0] || $mostrar[1]</a>
```

Pero no me deja usar los [ ] en el onclick.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el id al *query string*:

```
<a href='datosProducto.php?id=$mostrar[0]'> - $mostrar[0] || $mostrar[1]</a>
```

El cual podrás obtener en el segundo php con `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar algo como esto, para imprimir el id.

```
<?php
    $BBDD = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'datosSrDinner');
    $consultaProductos = $BBDD->query("SELECT nombre, descripcion FROM productos");
    while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaProductos)){
        echo "<tr><td><a id="link" href='datosProducto.php' data-id='$mostrar[0]'> - $mostrar[0] || $mostrar[1]</a></td></tr>";;
    }
 ?>
```

Y este script de javascript para recuperar el id y redireccionar a la página que deseas cargar.

```
   const link = document.querySelector('a#link');

   link.addEventListener('click', e => {
     const node = e.target;

     cosnt id = node.dataset.id; // este es el id que se imprimio del lado del servidor 

     window.location.href = `/page-url/${id}`;
     // or
     window.history.pushState({}, '', `/page-url/${id}`);
   })
```

Suerte!!.